# update ASP.NET Core WebApi project from 2.2 to 3.0 causing ExpandoObject JSON serialize error

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

My response object has load from MongoDB,  there is field was ExpandoObject,  after update to dotnet core 3.0, I keep got error like "Unable to cast object of type 'd__51' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'"

```html
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<GetExpandoEnumerator>d__51' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'.
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, ref WriteStack state)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<GetExpandoEnumerator>d__51' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'.
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleObject(JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int originalWriterDepth, int flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that's because Microsoft using its own JSON library "System.Text.Json" in dotnetcore3.0 as default. And the "System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer" can not serialize the dynamic "ExpendoObject" type that we used data Model from MongoDB.Driver.

so the solution is config the project to use NewtonsoftJson other than System.Text.Json.
reference link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

1.install NuGet package  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" (3.0.0)

2 in the Startup.cs update configureServices like below

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); 

    }
```